# Cant passing props via React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have class GetProfile extend the React.Component and return state in render. I want get the props GetProfile with react router but i got message

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
class GetProfile extends React.Component{
....
render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { 
                        data: this.state.data, 
                        department : this.state.department 
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default GetProfile;
```

In the Router.js this my code

```
import Home from './components/Home';
import GetProfile from './action/GetProfile';

....
<GetProfile>
   <Authenticated exact path="/home" render={(props) => <Home {...props.data}/>}/>
</GetProfile>
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try by importing React
import React from 'react'
class GetProfile extends React.Component{
    ....
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { 
                    data: this.state.data, 
                    department : this.state.department 
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
  }
 }
 export default GetProfile;
```